# How to create tabs inside a tab in ionic 4?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, ionic4

I am working with **ionic 4** and I am trying to implement **tabs inside a tab using angular routes**.

what I want to achieve is something like this:
[image]

here the tabs at the bottom are main tabs and one at the top should be seen when clicked on tab two of main tabs.

can anyone suggest how can I achieve it?

Comment: I went through the same thing a few years back. I don't think it's possible.

Comment: @SaurabhGupta Please provide an answer that solves your own question and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve is configuring the principal  routing in one file to keep all control.

Some like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        children:[
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () => import('../tab1/tab1.module').then(m => m.Tab1PageModule),
          },
          {
            path: 'details',
            component: DetailsPage,
            children:[
              {
                path: 'tab1-det1',
                component:Tab1Det1Page
                //loadChildren: () => import('../tab1/details/tab1-det1/tab1-det1.module').then( m => m.Tab1Det1PageModule)
              },
              {
                path: 'tab1-det2',
                loadChildren: () => import('../tab1/details/tab1-det2/tab1-det2.module').then( m => m.Tab1Det2PageModule)
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab2',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab2/tab2.module').then(m => m.Tab2PageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'tab3',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab3/tab3.module').then(m => m.Tab3PageModule)
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'tabs/tab1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'tabs/tab1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

In my case  DetailPage have the second tabs  , so keep on mind , that you need import too DetailPage like a component

path: 'details',
component: DetailsPage,
children:[
{
path: 'tab1-det1'

And in one of the tab where you put the second tab , add to the routing file then import to module

```
const routes: Routes = [
   {
     path: '',
    component: Tab1Page,
  },
  {
    path: 'details',
    loadChildren: () => import('./details/details.module').then( m => m.DetailsPageModule)
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class Tab1PageRoutingModule {}
```

One of the problem with this  (bug Ionic ), is in the second tab  , the parameter tab ='routing'  not working correctly , instead change with (click)="goTo('tabs/tab1/details/tab1-det2')" to some method like this:

```
goTo(page){
  this.router.navigate([page]);
}
```

And this is the result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXnPS.png)